# JSON-P request to URL does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsonp

I've been trying to get this to work for about three hours now.  Searched around, looked all over actually, and I tried all the examples people showed, none of which worked.  This is really starting to bug me.  What I'm trying to accomplish is a call to BitCoin Charts JSON file that holds all the bitcoin data.  I am setting up a webstore, and would like the price to be accurate when the user loads the page.

Here is the snippet of code where I call the $.getJSON() function:

```
function JSONCall() {
    var url = "http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/weighted_prices.json";
    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", Update);
}
function Update(data) {
    //there will be code here to change the HTML on my site, but for now, this works to test
    console.log(data);
}
```

The current error that I'm experiencing is:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/weighted_prices.json?callback=jQuery19100276493770070374_1387411109377&_=1387411109490". jquery-1.9.1.js:8336
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

and I cannot for the life of me get it to work.  My code looks fine, according to everything I've seen this far.  If anybody knows more about this than me and would be willing to help, that would be fantastic!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're making a cross-domain request which isn't allowed for security reasons. There are ways around it. Can you not get your service to obtain this information?

Answer (score 3):

I checked the URL and it doesn’t return JSONP, only plain JSON.

You will need to find another way, some options come to mind:

- Do a CORS request (cross-origin) if the service supports it
- Run via a server-side proxy
- See if the service supports JSONP in some other way